# Join Ubuntu PC to Windows domain, manage with Canonical's Landscape

Tags: networking, landscape

I'd like to join some Ubuntu 18.04 desktops to an existing Windows domain.

I'd also like to manage such desktops through Canonical's [Landscape.](https://landscape.canonical.com/)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Landscape does not preclude you from using things like SSSD to authenticate through AD. But it doesn't help or do any integration in that regard.